# checking the height of a div with jquery always returns 1

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get the height of a specific div.  I am doing so with:

```
var divHeight = $("#myDiv").height();
```

from the [JQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/height/)

```
<div style="width: 300px; height: 300px;"></div>
```

This `always returns 1` even though the height is hard-coded at `300px`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is the div hidden? Like `display:none;`?

Comment: it should work here http://jsfiddle.net/2b7VZ/1/ , also your `div` does not have any id assigned (which should be `myDiv`).

Comment: I've locked the question so it cannot be edited again. Please do not continue this behavior after the lock expires. I'll be back to check. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

As per JQuery documentation:

> Note that .height() will always return the content height, regardless
>   of the value of the CSS box-sizing property. As of jQuery 1.8, this
>   may require retrieving the CSS height plus box-sizing property and
>   then subtracting any potential border and padding on each element when
>   the element has box-sizing: border-box.

To avoid this penalty, use `.css( "height" )` rather than `.height().`

Comment: looks like you misunderstand about the so-called ***content height***. In fact it's the height of the inner region (does not include padding).

Comment: Can you post your exact code ? I dont see a point why it returns 1.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missing the `id` attribute in your `div`:

```
<div id="myDiv" style="width: 300px; height: 300px;"></div>
```

and I would use

```
$("#myDiv").css("height");
```